# NGINX passing requests to Pylons and relative URLs

Tags: nginx, pylons

I have NGINX running on port 8080. I have the following setup in my NGINX conf file.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  domain.com;

location / {
        #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:80  http://domain.com;
    }
```

These rules work correctly as far as I can tell. The only issue I run into is when Pylons gets a request for a relative URL it is using http://127.0.0.1/linkto/something instead of http://domain.com:8080/linkto/something. I believe I am missing something in my Pylons configuration, if you have any advice or need additional information just let me know. Thanks in advance for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) uses the hostname from the directive (127.0.0.1 in your case) as the Host: header for its request.  You probably just need to add [proxy_set_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header) Host $http_host; to have it pass through the original Host header to your backend.